# UIScrollView With Multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to use a UIScrollView to scroll through a few UIViews but it is not scrolling.  I've set it all up in interface builder.  Can anyone offer any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the content size of your scrollview in your code. Otherwise it doesn't know how far it needs to scroll. See the Apple docs here for more details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html